# slimScroll Start Bottom not working

Tags: jquery, slimscroll

I use slimScroll but when I would like to put a start bottom.
It's not working

This is my code :

```
<div id="slimScrollDiv" style="max-height:514px">   
    <div class="tickets_messages"></div>
        <script>
            var ticket_id = "<?php echo $msg_id; ?>";
        </script>
    <script src="js/tickets_support_messages.js"></script>
</div>
<script>
    $(function(){
        $('#slimScrollDiv').slimScroll({
            height: '',
            wheelStep: 5
        });
    });
</script>
```

thank you !

Comment: start: 'bottom'... is this not working?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It is difficult to offer solutions when the problem statement is simply, "it doesn't work".  Please [edit] your question to give a more complete description of what you expected to happen and how that differs from the actual results.  See [ask] for hints on what makes a good explanation.